# pvc volume different from kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubectl, kubernetes-pvc

in gke, there is a PVC.

```
$ kubectl -n team-x describe pvc kafka-data-0 | grep -r "Capacity"
(standard input):Capacity:      1Ti
```

but `kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{namespace=~"team-x", persistentvolumeclaim=~"kafka-data-0"}` returns `5410191745024`.

Any idea these two values are so different? Thanks

btw, `pvc:kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes:true_value{namespace=~"team-x", persistentvolumeclaim=~"kafka-data-0"}` returns `3854247874560`

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are asking for? In first one you have `stats_capacity_bytes` and in second `stats_available_bytes`. `Capacity` is total size, `available` is how much space you can use. Could you provide your YAMLs?

Comment: When you described your PVC, `1Ti` is value which was requested by you. `kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes` is `metric` and it show **Capacity in bytes of the volume.**. Could you provide your YAMLs about your kafka deployment/sts? How many PVCs are you using. Could you provide `kubectl get pv,pvc -A` ?